# Update existing facebook photo's attributes (including privacy)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app's created a photo for a user using the graph api and I can't find any documentation as to how to update any attributes of the photo. I'm especially curious about the privacy setting as I'd want to add more users to the whitelist to see the photo at a later date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not currently set the privacy level for a photo via API.

If you post a photo to the user’s wall, then the privacy level will be identical to the people that can see their wall contents;

if you upload a photo to a specific album, then the albums privacy settings will be inherited.

Only if your app creates an album for the user itself, then you can set the privacy level, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#albums And even that can’t be changed later via API, as far as I know.

Comment: Boo, i figured it was impossible but was hoping otherwise. Thanks